# Operator norm of product of two operators $A, B$ is sub-multiplicative in space of bounded operators

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $B(H)$ be a space of bounded linear operator on Hilbert space $H$. 
Where operator norm is defined as follows

$$\lVert A\rVert_{op} = \sup_{\lVert v\rVert = 1}\lVert Av\rVert$$

Show that for $A,B \in B(H)$ the inequality below is true:

$$\lVert AB\rVert_{op} \leq \lVert A\rVert_{op} \lVert B\rVert_{op}$$

My attempt:

$$\forall_{v\in H, \lVert v\rVert=1} \lVert (AB)v\rVert = \lVert A(Bv)\rVert = \lVert \lVert Bv \rVert \cdot A(\frac{Bv}{\lVert Bv\rVert})\rVert = 
\lVert Bv\rVert \cdot \lVert A(\frac{Bv}{\lVert Bv\rVert})\rVert \leq \lVert B \rVert_{op} \lVert A\rVert_{op}$$

$\Rightarrow \lVert AB \rVert_{op} \leq \lVert B \rVert_{op} \lVert A\rVert_{op}$

Is it correct?
My concern is division by $\lVert Bv \rVert$ under operator $A$ right after second equality sign. Is it allowed, if not how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you don't need to use the division by $||Bv||$ at all because you *know* that both $A$ and $B$ are bounded. Thus, we have:
$$||ABv|| = ||A(Bv)|| \le ||A||||Bv||\le ||A||||B||||v||$$
so that:
$$\frac{||ABv||}{||v||} \le ||A||||B||$$
so we can take the $\sup_{||v||=1}$ in the left hand side of the above equation. Note that I'm obviously assuming $v\neq 0$, once this is a trivial case of the inequality.

Comment: After your second equality what does the norm of $A$ mean? Sorry, I am missing something

Comment: Note that your hypothesis on $A$ and $B$ is that they are both bounded. This means that $||Ax|| \le ||A|| ||x||$ for every $x \in H$, where $||A||$ is your $||A||_{op}$.

Comment: Ok, now it is clear. Thank you.